# Jquery offset after appendTo

Tags: jquery

There is a simple code:

```
var wrap = $('<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" class="file-upload-wrapper"></div>').appendTo('.left-menu');
```

And then i try to get the position of the element, its returned wrong result

```
console.log(wrap.offset());
Object {top: 0, left: 0}
```

Experimentally, I found that when I put any delay, the correct result is returned

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log(wrap.offset());
}, 1);
Object {top: 92, left: 465}
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it without delay?

Comment: can you share css as well, cause I both get same values even in setTimeout

Comment: if think it is because of the time it takes to effectively add element to the dom. Not sure about this but have you tried with chaining like so: `var wrap = $('<div style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" class="file-upload-wrapper"></div>'); var offset = wrap.appendTo('.left-menu').offset();`?

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil i tried to delete all css and got same results.

Comment: @Kaddath Same result with your code.

Comment: i also get same values [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/vcqovkLx/)

Comment: ok, just read a comment somewhere that suggested it would be possible, is it just a test case or do you actually need to get an offset just right after the append? because working solutions i fell upon were quite "hacky" (consisting in adding classes or such, and test the DOM for a "ready state" with timeout functions.. not so great)

Comment: Oh, thank you guys, you prompted me where to find the problem. This is because i have a "tab menu" with hash tags, and parent of "wrap" was hidden before "window.load event" trigger then the tab becomes visible.